# How to configure IIS to forward invalid http requests to .net core

Tags: iis, hosting, web-hosting

I have moved an old web app from being hosted on a very old custom implementation of a web host using Cassini to .net core 2.2 hosted in IIS.

Since the old servers were a self implementation, it wasn't rejecting some requests that IIS is rejecting.

To be specific, the problem is with POST requests with no body and no Content-Length header, with a Transfer-Encoding header of "chunked". There is absolutely no reason not to use simple GET requests there, but this is the situation.

The requests are sent from an old plugin that some of the clients are using, and we can't make them upgrade it to a newer version that is sending valid GET requests. Currently IIS is rejecting the requests with a 502 code. Therefor, we need to maintain an old version of the server just for these clients.

I am looking for a way to configure IIS to forward these requests to the .net core web app despite being invalid and to handle them there (when tested on Kestrel without IIS, the results are returned as expected).
 
Thanks

Comment: Protocol violations are not tolerable in general, so you should fix such requests if you can. You might also use failed request tracing to analyze which module generates 502. If that comes from ASP.NET Core module, you can fork Microsoft's code and develop your own version.

Comment: It is definitely from IIS, it was tested on Kestrel without IIS and worked. Therefor the question is how to configure IIS, once the request passed IIS and continued down the pipeline we can handle it

Comment: maybe you don’t know, but ASP.NET Core module is part of ASP.NET Core, not IIS.

Comment: thanks, that got me in the right direction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with IIS that acted as a reverse proxy since I used out of process hosting. Once I switched to in process hosting the request went directly to the server and the problem was solved.
https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2019/Mar/16/ASPNET-Core-Hosting-on-IIS-with-ASPNET-Core-22